# In HTML ,how to place a new image to base image when i rollover my mouse to my base image such that both images are displayed side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am making a comic web page that has 2 cartoons. What I need is when an user moves his move over a cartoon, the the dialog/mind-thought of the comic should appear in the page

Can anybody help me out???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
.image .dialog-image {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
.image:hover .dialog-image {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://www.jamiesale-cartoonist.com/wp-content/uploads/cartoon-duck-free.png" alt="">
  <div class="dialog-image">
    <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/23875-200.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually this is what I was looking for.Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Give your dialog box a class (for ex. "dialog"), then add this css:

```
.dialog{
   position:absolute;
   z-index:2;
   display:none;
}

.dialog:hover{
   display:block;
}
```

`position:absolute;` if to get the dialog on top of the picture - you figure out the positioning based on your surrounding html